# In GridView Header Row DropDownList to select header column mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I Created a application which will map the data and save the Data fields. For that first row in my GridView I added new HearerRow with dropdownlist.
Below is my code which I have attached.

My HTML Page code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvDataMapping" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
</asp:GridView>
```

And Code Behind:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dtValues.Columns.Count; i++)
{
   BoundField boundfield = new BoundField();
   boundfield.DataField = dtValues.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString();
   boundfield.HeaderText = dtValues.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString();
   gvDataMapping.Columns.Add(boundfield);
}
gvDataMapping.DataSource = dtValues;
gvDataMapping.DataBind();

GridViewRow HeaderGridRow = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header,
                            DataControlRowState.Insert);
DropDownList ddlFieldValues;
TableCell HeaderCell;
foreach (DataColumn dc in dtValues.Columns)
{
    ddlFieldValues = new DropDownList();
    ddlFieldValues.ID = "FieldValues";
    ddlFieldValues.DataSource = (DataTable)Session["WorkItemTypeField"];
    ddlFieldValues.DataTextField = "FieldName";
    ddlFieldValues.DataValueField = "FieldID";
    ddlFieldValues.DataBind();
    ddlFieldValues.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", "0"));
    HeaderCell = new TableCell();
    HeaderCell.Controls.Add(ddlFieldValues);
    HeaderGridRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);
}
gvDataMapping.DataSource = dtValues;
gvDataMapping.DataBind();
gvDataMapping.Visible = true;
lblDataMapping.Visible = true;
gvDataMapping.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(1, HeaderGridRow);
```

See the [Click here to view screen displays the output of above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8O5w.png) . While clicking Save am not getting the GridView Header DropDowmList its showing null using below code.

```
            GridViewRow gvrow2 = gvDataMapping.HeaderRow;
            foreach (GridViewRow row in gvDataMapping.Rows)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < gvDataMapping.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    String header = gvDataMapping.Columns[i].HeaderText; //gets column name
                    DropDownList cellText = ((DropDownList)gvrow2.Cells[i].FindControl("FieldValues")); //Not getting the DDL returns null
                }
            }
```

**How to get the GridView Header row dropdownlist values in Save click event?**

Comment: that's because you repeated the id for each column. Assign a unique ID and try it again

Answer (score 0):

No guarantees, because I haven't tried this myself, but what about this code?

```
        GridViewRow gvrow1 = GrdDynamic1.HeaderRow;
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GrdDynamic1.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < GrdDynamic1.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                String header = GrdDynamic1.Columns[i].HeaderText;
                DropDownList cellText = ((DropDownList)gvrow1.Cells[i].FindControl("FieldValues"));
            }
        }
```

It looks as if you're looking for the drop down list in the right column, but not the right row:  you're looking in the data row, rather than the header row `gvrow1`.

Comment: Re-written the above Save button event code....       
where this line gets NULL while getting DDL.....DropDownList cellText = ((DropDownList)gvrow2.Cells[i].FindControl("FieldValues"));

Comment: Inspect `gvrow1.Cells[i]` in the debugger and see what it contains. You might be able to retrieve the control by its index, like `gvrow1.Cells[i].Controls[0]` (if the dropdown is the first control in the collection).